# Using Self-Join to find differences between rows

Tags: mysql

I have tried finding a solution to this question, but everything I've found has either asked a slightly different question or hasn't had an adequate answer. I have a table with the following setup:

```
    fullvna

    +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | startdate    | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | starttime    | time        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to find the time difference between each pair of consecutive lines, so the starttime of id=1 minus the starttime of id=2 (the table is ordered in reverse chronological order). I based my query off of what I found here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-tips/mysql-compare-calculate-difference-successive-rows/

```
    create table difference as SELECT 
                one.id,
                one.starttime,
                two.starttime,
                (one.starttime - two.starttime) AS diff
            FROM
                fullvna one
                    INNER JOIN
                fullvna two ON two.id = one.id + 1;
```

I'm receiving the following printout, and am not sure what it means or what I'm doing wrong:

```
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
     manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
     syntax to use near '  one.starttime,
        two.starttime,
        (one.starttime - two.starttime' at line 3
```

Comment: You should use [TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2)](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php)

Comment: Changing that row returns essentially the same error. Right now the date and time are broken up into two separate columns rather than one datetime value. Would that be why?

Comment: Doesnt make sense.  [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I can create a sample, but its a minimal, complete, and verifiable as I can make it. Is there something in particular that you need clarified?

Comment: your alias `One` is a reserved /keyword... perhaps wrap it in backticks to escape it? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html or use a different non-keyword alias

Comment: @xQbert I would never guess that one.

Comment: didn't you mean `one` with backticks?  Whenever i seed odd behavior and the SQL looks right; it's the first thing I check.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I know. I thought you were being punny. so I reciprocated

Comment: @xQbert I changed it from one to a1 (same with the two) and its still giving the same error.

Comment: Does the select run w/o the create?  Could you have null values in a column which the engine can't determine what datatype to use?  nevermind alias the starttime column both times... can't create a table w/ same named column twice (starttime)  One_StartTime, Two_StartTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have hidden characters that are displayed as spaces, but they're not and they're causing the error. Copy the query from my answer. And as Juan suggested, it is recommended to use the `TIMEDIFF()` function instead of subtracting them:

```
CREATE TABLE difference AS
SELECT one.id,
       one.starttime AS starttime,
       two.starttime AS endtime,
       TIMEDIFF(one.starttime, two.starttime) AS diff
FROM fullvna one
INNER JOIN fullvna two ON two.id = one.id + 1;
```

**EDIT** As xQbert mentioned, you need to use different names for the `starttime` column, so I corrected the query above accordingly.

Comment: I need to create a table because I'll be running queries on the result later. Running this produces the same error as I was receiving before though.

Comment: "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'one.starttime,
       two.starttime,
       TIMEDIFF(one.starttime, two.st' at line 2"

Comment: check @xQbert comment.  `one` is a reserved word

Comment: can't create a table with the same named column (starttime)

Comment: Interesting. I'm wondering if somehow the formatting did throw it off because as far as I can tell this is word for word what I put in (after I switched to using timediff) but just editing my previous query didn't run while copying and pasting this did. In case anyone stumbles upon this in the future: you one being a reserved keyword did not have any effect, and this code works once you add in column names.

Comment: @caitlin aliasing starttime I think is what fixed it.

Comment: That's because like I said, you're query contains hidden characters. You don't see them, but they cause the error, so editing your query will not solve the issue unless you delete all those hidden characters. That' what I did in my answer, I deleted the hidden characters from your query.

Comment: @xQbert I first copied and pasted the code as written and the error message changed to something that was very obvious what it meant(Duplicate column name 'starttime') so while that was an issue it definitely wasn't the source of the initial error.

Comment: Good to know special non-display characters in the SQL were root w/ secondary problem

Comment: @xQbert Yes, you cannot use the same name twice. My answer was focused on solving the OP issue. I corrected it with your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @RacilHilan I guess that's what I get for trying to copy and paste the code from somewhere then edit it, rather than writing it from scratch

Comment: Yes, when you copy some code from HTML pages, you need to clean it first. There is nothing wrong with copying and we all do it, but never use it as is without cleaning.

Answer (score 3):

- Don't use alias `one` as it's a keyword pick a different one
- alias startime as two columns with same name in a create table will not work.
- timediff (as others  mentioned in comments)

.

```
 CREATE TABLE difference as 
 SELECT a1.id
      , a1.starttime as OneStartTime
      , a2.starttime as TwoStartTime
      , TIMEDIFF(a1.starttime, a2.starttime) AS diff
 FROM fullvna a1
 INNER JOIN fullvna a2
    ON a2.id = a1.id + 1;
```

Comment: Looks like the real problem was the duplicated column name. Here is a working [DEMO](http://rextester.com/FFCZ42748) the alias `'one'` even when reserved doesnt give any error.

Comment: Na real problem was non-display character (other than a space) then the column name.

Comment: what non-display character? and how you saw it?

Comment: take a look at comments under @RacilHilan  OP indicates such a problem and after fixing it error changed to duplicate column name.  I didn't see it, inferred from comments.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Here is a simple way to see the hidden characters: copy the query in the question and paste it in MS-Word, then click the button that displays the hidden characters. The spaces will be displayed as dots, and the hidden characters that are causing the issue here are displayed as circles.

Comment: Ok, I see those, but still was weird, because I copy paste the question to rextester and didnt have that issue. I got the duplicate column name right away.

Comment: Agree but the error message was different so your copy/paste test didn't reproduce the original error.  somehow copy/paste doesn't include the non-display characters or converts them after the copy from SO... strange no doubt.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Perhaps rextester removes those hidden characters. No that's not strange, each tool handles characters differently. After all, rextester is not a word processor like MS Word.

Comment: I just copied and pasted my initial query from SO (to see what would happen) and it gives the same error it had been, so they definitely get removed on rextester's end.

Comment: @Caitlin btw did you see the [DEMO](http://rextester.com/FFCZ42748) link?  That is what I mean like a MCV sample, something we can work and test. Next time if you provide it we can help you much quicker and wont waste time trying to guess.